# insert into table and skip duplicates

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

My stored procedure has 3 parameters i'm passing `(@nameP, @idP, @dateP`)
and is inserting the data in a  `#myTemp` table

then i use

```
 select * 
    into dbo.realTable
    from #myTemp
```

and then I want to filter out any data which already exists (in `dbo.FinalTable`)based on `dateP` and `idP`:

```
insert into dbo.FinalTable 
select * from dbo.realTable
where not exists (select * from dbo.FinalTable
where idP = @idP
and dateP = @dateP)

drop table dbo.realTable
```

The data is appended to the table, when i execute my procedure. The problem is that if i put the same `idP` and execute it again for the same `dateP`, it shouldn't insert anything but it does. I think the problem might be in the `insert into` part.

### EDIT:

this works perfectly if i remove `and dateP = @dateP` from the where clause)
ps: thank you all for your answers, even if in my case i simply had to do what i wrote above, I learned from your answers

Comment: Look at `MERGE` command. Another point could be a `SELECT DISTINCT`. Ad please provide sample data and expected output,

Comment: When I run your code it doesn't insert the second time.

Comment: the *@name* is not mentioned anywhere. How is that used ?

Comment: @name is actually the linked db i'm connecting to

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically you have used `not exists` which is absolutely correct. the problem in you query for next time is `@dateP`. If you pass same `@idP` but different `@dateP` then same `@idp` get created because your getting validate against @idp and `@dateP`. So how you protect that, think about your business scenario for duplicate, duplicate means for only `@idp` or `@idp` and `@datep`, if both then your query is correct but if only `@idp` then you have to remove `@dateP` from your `where` clause.

Comment: thank you. In order to solve it i had to remove @dateP from the where clause. That did it!

Answer (score 4):

this inserts all rows from realtable do finaltable, where the combination of idP and dateP is NOT existing...(using a simple left join):

```
INSERT INTO dbo.FinalTable 
SELECT * 
FROM    dbo.RealTable R
        LEFT JOIN dbo.FinalTable T ON T.idP = R.idP 
        AND T.dateP = R.dateP
WHERE T.idP IS NULL
```

I would strongly recommend the use of column names instead of "*"!!

```
INSERT INTO table (column1, column2)
SELECT column1, column2 FROM anothertable
```

Comment: i'm using * because i have a lot of columns there. I will test your code in a minute. Thanks

Comment: this will add data from other days, if there is a match from that same day. You have also neglected to use the parameters.

Answer (score 3):

A Merge Statement is the most efficient way to achieve this

```
MERGE dbo.FinalTable  AS TARGET 
USING dbo.RealTable AS SOURCE ON TARGET.idP = SOURCE.idP AND TARGET.dateP = SOURCE.dateP
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
INSERT 
(
name
,idp
,datep
)
VALUES
(
 SOURCE.name
,SOURCE.idp
,SOURCE.datep

);
```

Comment: you have no mention of the parameters

Comment: this looks like a bad idea but the performance with this is not so good, is it? My procedure exports data in 40 sec - 1 min. When i added this part it takes way longer. After 6 minutes i stopped it because i am not supposed to query the server for extended periods of time

Comment: In the first comment wanted to say "looks like a good idea" . tried it again, stopped it at ~ 10 minutes

Comment: I have 19 columns and @ 180.000-190.000 rows for every execute

Comment: A non clustered Index on the join columns of the target could significantly improve performance.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, do not create a table inside a procedure just to drop it again later. This can cause problems if multiple calls to the procedure are executed.

You already have a temporary table that you can use.

Your code fails because you take all rows or no rows. You have not made a proper join:

```
not exists (select * from dbo.FinalTable
where idP = @idP
and dateP = @dateP)
```

Try this instread:

```
INSERT dbo.FinalTable -- (you should name columns instead of using wildchar)
SELECT *
FROM dbo.realTable rt
WHERE
  not exists
  (
    SELECT *
    FROM dbo.FinalTable ft
    WHERE
      rt.idP = idP
      and **rt**.dateP = **ft**.dateP
      )
  and 
    idP = @idP
  and
    dateP = @dateP
```

Comment: thanks, will test your solution. I am naming the columns, just changed the names to be able to post here\

Comment: you wanted to write `insert into dbo.FinalTable` on your first row, right?

Comment: tried your code, was happy at first that it worked. Then left `nameP` the same, `dateP` the same, changed the `idP` . And it doesn't insert anything else if i execute it again. Since it's a different `id` all those fields should have been inserted